# Едет сайт после очистки кеша в Drupal. Как все вернуть

Tags: cms, drupal

Дали сайт на доработку. Нашел блок, который нужно отредактировать, изменил код, залил новый. 
Очистил кеш в Drupal, чтобы отобразились изменения. После этого слетела вся верстка, вылезли системные ошибки с неизвестными переменными. Пробовал вернуть файл, но с этим это не связано.
Сайт недавно переносили с одного хостинга на другой.

Видимо данные стилей (стили меню и боковых блоков) брались из кэша, а теперь не подгужаются.

Главный вопрос, можно ли вернуть кэш обратно? Есть ли какое-то востановление?

Собственно ссылка на сайт http://vistaoptical.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо вопрос уже не актуален, но всё же.

Кэш хранится в БД и единственный способ его вернуть это восстановить БД из бэкапа.

Но проблема не в этом, так как кэш как правило не хранится вечно, а периодически обновляется. Скорее всего проблема в контенте блока, предположительно не были закрыты html теги, а системными ошибками надо разбираться индивидуально.

Comment: Не знаю, с чем было связано, но нашел в на форуме Друпала решение моей проблемы (с вопросом она не сильно связана, кеш восстанавливать не пришлось). Если используются несколько тем, как в моем случае - кеш нужно почистить по очереди на всех подтемах. Видимо идет какой-то конфликт и верстка слетает + системные ошибки. Не находит некоторые переменные.

Comment: После переключения тем и чистки кеша - все пришло в норму.